# Masking driver bits with C

Tags: c, binary, hex, driver, masking

I'm working on a driver, and I'm having trouble finding a way to manipulate the bits I want to on a digital register.

The register has 20 bits (0-19) and I'm only concerned with writing over the last two (19,18).  These bits are part of a hex representing that section, so to visualize, the #'s are what I want to change:

Hex    5    B    0    F

[##00 0101 1011 0000 1111]

All of the other bits must be kept as they are—the example above is arbitrary, so the masking has to handle any combination of bits.

I've tried creating a mask with any combination of `&` and `|` with `0xFFFFF` and also `0x00000` but neither change *just* the first two bits of the hex that will be written.

Any ideas to get this to function would be great; and if you could explain how the solution works, even better.

Comment: What is the expected result? Should the ## be always 0? or always 1? or some arbitrary combination?

Comment: Since my answer was cut short when the question was singlehandedly marked as duplicate and the linked answer only gives general hints about bit-fiddling: You need `a = (a & ~(3 << 18)) | (i << 18);` Here, `a` is the original value and `i` is a value from 0 to 3 that you wish to set bits 18 and 19 to.